# Governmental vs Gubernatorial Usage

Tags: grammaticality

When do we use 'governmental' vs 'gubernatorial?'

I was writing:

> How did this lead to new legislation and *** policies?

When I noticed that although 'governmental' sounded more fitting, 'gubernatorial' is another similar adjective that is perhaps more correct.

A related question on etymology is [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26916/why-do-we-use-gubernatorial-as-an-adjective).

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you say that 'gubernatorial' is perhaps more correct? It sounds archaic in my opinion. And, appaarently, in that of many others {[Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=governmental%2Cgubernatorial+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgovernmental%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgubernatorial%3B%2Cc0)}. Thinking that choosing a word with a 'better pedigree' is more correct is indulging in the etymological fallacy; usage drives acceptability.

Comment: They refer to different things. A governor is not a government and vice versa. Which is more appropriate in your context is impossible for us to answer.

Comment: I am discussing the effects of the discovery of stem cells (1998-2000) on the laws and policies that were created and enforced. Does that help with the context?

Answer (score 1):

**Gubernatorial**:
If you are in the US, gubernatorial refers only to the office of the governor of one of the 50 states.

**Governmental**:
This can mean government at the federal, state or local level.